# Design a compiler like C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, syntax, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm developing a C like compiler and I want to know how the compiler works with the system include.

The compiler read the entire code, and stores all includes found in one list and parser the includes, after finish the reading the current code?

```
// file main.c
#include <stdio.h> // store in one list

// continue the parse ...
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
// now, read the includes
// after finish the includes parse, gen code of sources

// just a sample
// file stdio.h
#include <types.h> // store in list
#include <bios.h>  // store in list

void printf(...)
{
}

void scanf(...)
{
}
```

Btw, I have developd an system ( only test ) to read the includes and, stop the parse, to read the include... ( it's a disgusting code, but, work... )
( link of sample ) -> https://gist.github.com/4399601

Btw, What is the best way to read the includes... and work with includes files ??

Comment: I just hop that you are not trying to implement the parser in C... There are better language for that, for example Bison

Comment: You need to be careful with terminology. C isn't a compiler, it's a language. Do you want to write a C compiler, or a compiler for a language like C?

Comment: Or you want to make a complete language say "Alexa" ? If so, then you can create a full application in C or C++ or Java, once it is done, then refactor your code in your language.

Comment: If you're trying to implement it like C does, then crack open your copy of the C standard and see what it says to do. It says to look for, in an implementation-defined manner, the file name between `<` and `>`, and replace that `#include` directive line with the entire contents of that file. There is no storing and refering to later, it's all as it goes; this is a major reason why compiling C and C++ is so slow.

Comment: well, for start you need a **lexer**, after that you can cache and analyze what you want, but the first step is the lexer.

Comment: @GManNickG: Replace the `#include` with the contents of the include file... after interpolating macros so that `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` reflect where they appeared.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well I was vague on "replace". ;)

Comment: @GManNickG: Nothing wrong with your comment.. I just wanted to highlight `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` in this context, because they do complicate matters quite a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`#include`, `#define`, `#ifdef` and the like are processed by a separate pass called the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). It replaces the lines with `#include` with the included files. The resulting temporary source text is then fed to later passes like the [tokenizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: And the conceptual file containing preprocessed output *can* be an actual temporary file, but a pipe (between processes) or stream (inside the process) are also viable options.

Answer (score 1):

Any line in C that begins with # is handled by the preprocessor, not the compiler. The preprocessor generates a file that the compiler then compiles. The contents of the file depend on whatever is #defined by the developer and the SDK.

Comment: I don't find making this distinction useful, here. A C compiler, for example, contains a preprocessor, "compiler", and linker, but the whole thing is still a C compiler. The word is overloaded.

Comment: @GManNickG preprocessing can either be a stage in a single compiler exe or a separate program. All that matters is that it happens before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Anything which begins with **#** is a preprocessor directive.. the corresponding code gets substituted at the time of compilation.. the first stage of compilation is this preprocessor compilation..

then later the output of preprocessor(.i file) is given to the later stages of compilation..

later stages of compilation include LEXICAL ANALYZER, PARSER, OPTIMIZER and CODE GENERATOR..

Answer (score 0):

If I was writing a compiler from scratch, I would first of all consider if handing includes is a necessary part of the language - and if so, do YOU have to write it, or could you use an already existing one (such as the cpp part of gcc). The "fun" part of a compiler, after all, is the real compiling of the code, not reading files and replacing strings with other strings through macro expansion [although that can be quite fun too, of course - but you can write that once you have a compiler that works!].

The tricky part with include files isn't the including itself (fairly trivial, recursive, function), but the parsing of #define/#ifdef/#if/#undef, and more importantly, the replacing stuff with that.

Have fun!